# Phonegap: app for iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cordova

I have Snow Leopard Mac OS and old version of xcode and iOS SDK (xcode v. 3.2 and SDK 4) and for some reason I can't update it right now, but I need to keep developing as is. Later, I'm going to update my app to SDK 5, app wont be too complicated for it.

But I got a problem with Phonegap. The latest version (that available on their website) doesn't support old xcode and SDK, as I understood. With proper installion there are 15 errors after building app (with blank, "non"-touched index.html).

The question is can I fix somehow the latest release of Phonegap for working with old xcode, or I have to search older Phonegap? 
Or maybe, I'm wrong at all, and the problem not in versions, but in something else.
Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you should be able to run it on old xcode and sdk, what are the specific errors you are getting?

Comment: For some reason, project was installed inccorect. In "Classes" folder there are only AppDelegate files, but there is no PhoneGapDelegate files, so I got "PhoneGapDelegate.h:No such files or directory". But also, there is one error that I cant understand: "Command /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp failed with exit code 1"

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "For some reason I can't update [Xcode] right now", my guess is that you installed it via the App Store. The App Store version has been updated to Xcode 4.2 for Lion, so if you are still on Snow Leopard you can't update via that route. However, you *can* download XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard manually via the iOS Dev Centre if you are a Registered Apple Developer...